# Why doesn't this Java code do the same as this C++ code? (basic operations; C++ output is correct)

Tags: java, c++

Problem: C++ code outputs correct answer. Java's is +- a few of correct answer. Original problem I'm trying to solve is [here](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/520/B). C++ code found [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/520/submission/10834744). I know little to nothing about C++, but am trying to learn by replicating in Java.

**Java:**

```
public class twobuttons
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first = sc.nextInt();
        int second = sc.nextInt();
        int moves;

        if (second <= first)
        {
            System.out.println(first - second);
            // System.out.println("one");
            return;
        }

        int a = 0;

        while(first < second)
        {
            if (second%2 == 0)
                second++;
            else
                second /= 2;
            a++;
        }

        a += (first - second);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

**C:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// code taken from http://codeforces.com/contest/520/submission/10834744
// retyped to begin learning basic operations in c++ ... and submit something that would work

main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int first, second;
    cin >> first >> second; // get first and second numbers from system

    // cout << 10 - 5 << endl;

    if (second <= first)
    {
        cout << first-second << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int answer = 0;
    while(first < second)
    {
        // cout << (first%2);
        if(second % 2)  // if 0 == true in c++
            second++;
        else
            second /= 2;
        answer++;
        // cout << second;
        // cout << "\n";
    }

    answer+= ( first-second );
    cout << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `int moves;` ?

Comment: There's nothing like step-by-step debugging to help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

`if(second % 2)` means `if(second % 2 != 0)`. You wrote `==`.

Answer (score 1):

0 is considered false in C.  So "if(second%2)" means "if(second%2 !=0)" and not as you wrote...